# Feynman on Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, history

In 1964, Feynman stated that

> "Heisenberg noticed, when he discovered the laws of quantum mechanics, that the new laws of nature that he'd discovered could only be consistent if there was some basic limitation to our experimental abilities that had not been previously recognized. In other words, you can't experimentally be as delicate as you wish. And he proposed his uncertainty principle, which, stated in terms of our experiment, is the following. (He stated it another way, but they're exactly equivalent. You can get from one to the other.)
>
> > It is impossible to design any apparatus whatsoever to determine through which hole the electron passes that will not at the same time disturb the electron enough to destroy the interference pattern.
>
> And no one has found a way around this."
>
> (Feynman (1964). The Character of Physical Law. Messenger Lectures. MIT Press.)

Is this still accurate today? Has no one yet found a way around this? And is Feynman's characterization of the problem (not as some metaphysica issue, but simply a material experimental limitation) still correct?

Answer (score 8):

> And is Feynman's characterization of the problem (not as some metaphysical issue, but simply a material experimental limitation) still correct?

This is actually wrong.

When Heisenberg first derived it, he was deriving it from purely theoretical grounds (and in the correct way, in fact), but in the zeal to try to communicate it to other physicists, he got caught up in a fallacious reasoning on the experiments and that happened to catch on.

What is really happening is that, from Fourier analysis, we know that there are conjugate ways to look at them, e.g. we can look at the wave in time, or we can look at the wave in frequency, and these conjugate ways necessarily have a relationship in the information that they carry. In particular, if you want to know the frequency of a wave to extreme precision, then the wave must be infinitely spread out in time and thus the location of the centre of the wave will be incredibly imprecise. [3Blue1Brown recently gave a *beautiful presentation of this topic,* thinking that he was only talking about something adjacent to the HUP, when in fact he covered the entirety of it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4)

***This is a necessary mathematical fact and has very little to do with experiments.***

Except for two caveats:

1. Because everything in our universe is made of quantum materials, this means that our experiments must also obey HUP.
2. The actual derivation of what experimental uncertainties must obey, is an inequality that is larger than the HUP limits, not always possible to come down to it.

*It is in this sense that Feynman's characterisation is still correct, and will continue to be correct unless we find something that overthrows quantum theory.*

In particular, it is ***not*** that humans are too stupid to have yet to invent a way to measure things better than the HUP limits. It is that **mathematics forbids the information we wish for, to even exist.**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149133/discussion-on-answer-by-naturallyinconsistent-feynman-on-heisenbergs-uncertaint); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.